# Find the maximum of count in a grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have a dataframe that consists of football data with columns such as player name, club, nationality and rating. I have applied the `groupby` function to group the data by club and nationality and have calculated the count, min, max and mean. 
[image: five column table]

Now, I need to display the clubs and nation with the maximum count for that club. For example, Hoffenheim has 10 German nationals and that is the maximum for the club. How can I do that?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1):

I think need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first level of `MultiIndex` with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) and then select rows by `loc`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'club':list('AABBCC'),
                   'min':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   'mean':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'max':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'count':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'nationality':list('aaabbb')}).set_index(['club','nationality'])

print (df)
                  min  mean  max  count
club nationality                       
A    a              4     7    1      5
     a              5     8    3      3
B    a              4     9    5      6
     b              5     4    7      9
C    b              5     2    1      2
     b              4     3    0      4

df = df.loc[df.groupby(level=1)['count'].idxmax()]
print (df)
                  min  mean  max  count
club nationality                       
B    a              4     9    5      6
     b              5     4    7      9
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.groupby(level=1)['count'].idxmax())
nationality
a    (B, a)
b    (B, b)
Name: count, dtype: object
```

Comment: I need to find the maximum players from which nation for club a,b,c,d,e and f.

Comment: @ShreyGrover - OK, then need `df.loc[df.groupby(level=0)['count'].idxmax()]`

Comment: @ShreyGrover - Btw, be free modify your question with some sample data (e.g. copy my DataFrame for prevent downvotes)